# how do i print items in list until they reach a certain number of lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a coding exercise where you can't remember the lyrics to a song and after a certain amount of printed verses the code prints "I give up". I need to create code to print lyrics in a list, line by line, again and again, until it hit's the a certain amount of lines and then it prints "I give up". I'm stuck, trying to figure out how to print x amount of lines per the variable but I've only figured out how to print the list x amount of times.

I've figured out how to print x lists but I dont know how to print only x lines from the variable.

```
lyrics = ["I wanna be your endgame", "I wanna be your first string",
          "I wanna be your A-Team", "I wanna be your endgame, endgame"]

lines_of_sanity = 6

for x in range(lines_of_sanity):
    for i in (lyrics):
        print(i)
```

It prints the complete list of lyrics 6 times but I need it to print the elements within the list 6 times, and then continue until the verse completes and print ("I give up")

The correct code, given the variables should be :

> I wanna be your endgame
>   I wanna be your first string
>   I wanna be your A-Team
>   I wanna be your endgame, endgame
>   I wanna be your endgame
>   I wanna be your first string
>   I wanna be your A-Team
>   I wanna be your endgame, endgame
>   I GIVE UP

Comment: Can you give an example of what you wantt he output to look like? It's not totally clear to me from the description what you need it to do.

Comment: `for i in (lyrics):
    for x in range(lines_of_sanity):
        print(i)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you mean? Sorry if this is not what you meant...

```
lyrics = ["I wanna be your endgame", "I wanna be your first string",
      "I wanna be your A-Team", "I wanna be your endgame, endgame"]

lines_of_sanity = 6

for i in range(lines_of_sanity):
    print(lyrics[i%len(lyrics)])

print("I GIVE UP")
```

in response to your comment, maybe someone can simplify

```
for i in range(lines_of_sanity+len(lyrics)-(lines_of_sanity%len(lyrics))):
    print(lyrics[i%len(lyrics)])

print("I GIVE UP")
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I need. Thank you. The last part is finishing the verse. So for this variable, I would need to add "I wanna be your A-Team
I wanna be your endgame, endgame" to finish off the verse.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to repeat the full lyrics enough to at least print some number of lines. So in this case you will print the full lyrics twice. You can calculate the number with:

```
times = math.ceil(6/len(lyrics))
```

With that a nice way to do this is to use [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) together with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). Put together it would look like:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
import math

lyrics = ["I wanna be your endgame", "I wanna be your first string",
          "I wanna be your A-Team", "I wanna be your endgame, endgame"]

lines_of_sanity = 6
times = math.ceil(lines_of_sanity/len(lyrics))

for l in chain.from_iterable(repeat(lyrics, times)):
    print(l)
print("I GIVE UP")
```

Which will print 2 full verses then give up.

Comment: bit more pythonic!